# Cannot import pvclust by using rpy2 in python3.6 (Jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, rpy2, pvclust

I am using Jupyter notebook in anaconda and try to use the pvclust to perform hierarchical clustering on my data. 
My codes:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
pandas2ri.activate()
base = importr("base")
pvclust = importr("pvclust")
```

But I got the error:

```
RRuntimeError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-291b18105962> in <module>()
      3 pandas2ri.activate()
      4 base = importr("base")
----> 5 pvclust = importr("pvclust")
      6 # data = robjects.DataFrame.from_csvfile(filepath + folders[0]      + '\\vcfA_filled.csv')
      7 # data

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rpy2-2.9.1-py3.6-win-amd64.egg\rpy2  \robjects\packages.py in importr(name, lib_loc, robject_translations, signature_translation, suppress_messages, on_conflict, symbol_r2python,  symbol_check_after, data)
    451     if _package_has_namespace(rname, 
    452                               _system_file(package = rname)):
--> 453         env = _get_namespace(rname)
    454         version = _get_namespace_version(rname)[0]
    455         exported_names = set(_get_namespace_exports(rname))

RRuntimeError: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called 'pvclust'
```

It seems I need to install the pvclust first? But I am using jupyter notebook (python3.6) launched by anaconda and I am confused how to get a R package like this preinstalled and then import from rpy2?

P.S. Is there any Python package that can perform hierarchical clustering with p-value? All I need is to use some function that can bootstrap my data and cluster the data with p-values.

Thanks a lot.